# Indian ETA photo is horizontal

Tags: visas, india, e-visas

My Indian ETA has been granted today but my photo ID above the barcode is horizontal not vertical. Will this be sufficient or cause problems at immigration?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Who cares about the orientation of the photo, you will be fine, don't overthink it

Comment: If worse comes to worst, they can just tilt their head to the side when going through immigration...